# Cannot find dispatch method{} for Webservice issue

Tags: web-services, soap

I am trying to access webservice but getting following error while marshelling the service at my end. The following error comes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
   <S:Body> 
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
         <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode> 
         <faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com}getCustomerOnboardingDetailsRequest</faultstring> 
      </S:Fault> 
   </S:Body> 
</S:Envelope>
```

The Spring web service tempelate is use to marshel the request for the operation but it fails and produce the above error. When i import the same WSDl in soap UI and generate the request then the request is correct but when the request is marsheled by spring web service tempelate then the generated request is missing request wrapper class which leads to above exception.

```
here is WSDL and XSD 

**WSDL** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.11-b150616.1732 svn-revision#a247ba216861f2c0baac9a3657c5690bce0c744d.--><!--Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.11-b150616.1732 svn-revision#a247ba216861f2c0baac9a3657c5690bce0c744d.--><definitions targetNamespace="http://impl.customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com/" name="CustomerMgmtWebService" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <import namespace="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com" location="customermgmt.wsdl"/>
  <binding name="CustomerMgmtWebServiceImplPortBinding" type="ns1:CustomerMgmtWebService" xmlns:ns1="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <operation name="getCustomerOnboardingDetails">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com"/>
      </output>
      <fault name="CustomerServiceRuntimeFault">
        <soap:fault name="CustomerServiceRuntimeFault" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
      <fault name="InValidRequestFault">
        <soap:fault name="InValidRequestFault" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="CustomerMgmtWebService">
    <port name="CustomerMgmtWebServiceImplPort" binding="tns:CustomerMgmtWebServiceImplPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://10.5.194.63:7002/m2mws/services/customermgmt"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>

**XSD**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.11-b150616.1732 svn-revision#a247ba216861f2c0baac9a3657c5690bce0c744d.--><xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com" xmlns:tns="http://customer.services.ws.m2m.airtel.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="getCustomerOnboardingDetailsRequest" type="tns:getCustomerOnboardingDetailsRequest"/>
  <xs:element name="getCustomerOnboardingDetailsResponse" type="tns:getCustomerOnboardingDetailsResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="getCustomerOnboardingDetailsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="pageNo" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="pageRecordsCount" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="requestedBy" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="getCustomerOnboardingDetailsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="customer_onboarding_details_array" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="customerOnboarding" type="tns:customerOnboarding" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="customerOnboarding">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="customerOnboardingId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="customerAccountNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="customerType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="totalReceivedSIMs" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="actualInsertedSIMs" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="errorSIMs" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="emailAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="jobOrderId" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="createdBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="validatedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="createdOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="validatedOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="remarks" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="attribute1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="attribute2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```